# How to use django-rules predicates with nested serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rules

I have a few models in my application which use [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules) to define permissions. More precisely, I have `predicates` which are used in the `rules_permissions` (inside the model's `Meta`) dictionary, under the `view` key. I am using [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for views and serializers.

I'd like to restrict the views to **not** serialize nested data for which the user does not have the `view` permission. The code works fine for a single level of serialisation, but the predicates for nested objects are never evaluated.

For example, I have a `Project` model, and when querying for `/projects/3/`, the following data is returned:

```json
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test Project",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user": 2,
            "test": "test_adam"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "user": 3,
            "test": "test_eve"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, as a user *Adam*, I should not be able to see the `Data` object which belongs to *Eve*. I should only see the serialised data for `Data` object with `"id": 3`.

So I've written a `is_data_owner` predicate and added it to `rules_permissions` of my `Data` class. But that predicate function is never called when querying for `/projects/3/`, even though the serializer is accessing the `Data` model to create the above, nested serialisation. I'd expect that since predicates related to `Project` are running and working just fine, all nested models accessed by the serializer will also have their predicates checked. But that's not the case.

Note: I am open to other tools which could provide the object-level permissions I need. I've used `django-rules` as I thought it would meet all my needs, and also because I like the idea of predicates and not having to store permissions in the database.

Serializer code (as requested):

```py
class DataSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ["id", "user", "test"]


class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    data = DataSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["id", "name", "data"]
```

Note that I am aware I could write the code in the serializer class to restrict the data that is returned, but I'm not very keen on having to write this (or even remember to do so) for every scenario. I'd instead prefer this all happened automatically.

```
class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    data = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_data(self, instance: Project):
        permission = instance.data.model.get_perm("view")

        return DataSerializer(instance.data.filter(id__in=[
            item.id for item in instance.data.all() if rules.has_perm(permission, self.context["request"].user, item)
        ]), many=True).data
```

If nothing works out of the box I will most likely just spend time preparing a custom serializer base class to automatically do it for me, for selected fields. But I would find it strange that this scenario isn't supported by some external tool already...

Comment: could you add serializer code

Comment: Are you filtering for the `user`?

Comment: @Memristor Sorry, not sure I understand. I'm not manually filtering, but I confirm the permissions depend on the user. For example, the `is_data_owner` predicate looks like this: `data.user == user`, where `data` is an instance of `Data`, and `user` is an instance of my app's user model, both being passed to the predicate (the signature is `is_data_owner(user, data)`)

@YusufAdel Code added